# Computing homology of complement of an embedding

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology

Let $I=[0,1]$ and $S^3$ the $3$-sphere. Assume we have injective maps $f_1,f_2:I\to S^3$ such that $\mathrm{Im}f_1\cap\mathrm{Im}f_2=\emptyset$. I have the following problem:

> Compute $H_*(S^3-\mathrm{Im}f_1\cup\mathrm{Im}f_2)$, giving exlicit generators.

I am only allowed to use chapter 2 and chapter 3 before Poincaré Duality from Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*.

I know by compactness and Hausdorffness that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are embeddings.

What I first did was considering tubular neighborhoods $N_1$ and $N_2$ of $\mathrm{Im}f_1$ and $\mathrm{Im}f_2$, respectively, which must be contractible, and then Mayer-Vietoris would show everything via decomposition $S^3=(S^3-\mathrm{Im}f_1\cup\mathrm{Im}f_2)\cup (N_1\cup N_2)$. However, it seems that stronger conditions are needed in order to consider tubular neighborhoods, so this method was wrong.

From Alexander Duality I know what the homology groups are, but that theorem comes after Poincaré Duality, so I cannot use it.

**Question**

Can I somehow justify the existence of contractible neighborhoods $N_1$ and $N_2$ even though they are not tubular? Is there a better way to approach this problem? If possible, I would like a method that also works for embeddings of other compact manifolds such as the Möbius band and $S^1$.

**Edit** In section 2.B of Hatcher there is a proof for the case of an embedding $h:D^k\to S^n$. I don't know if it is possible to adapt this theorem to an arbitrary (at least finite) number of copies of $D^k$ being embedded by different embeddings, but that would definitely help.

Comment: Can you compute it if you replace $S^3$ by $\mathbb{R}^3$ ? If so then you can use Mayer-Vietoris to remove a point from $S^3$ and get to $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: @Max I think I have the exact same problem in $\mathbb{R}^3$  so the answer is no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed make use of the proof from Hatcher Section 2.B. Presumably what that result gives you is trivial reduced homology in all dimensions for $S^n - h(D^k)$.

The way you use it is not to decompose $S^3 - (\text{Im}(f_1) \cup \text{Im}(f_2))$ but instead to decompose $S^3$ itself.

Let $U_1 = S^3 - \text{Im}(f_1)$ and let $U_2 = S^3 - \text{Im}(f_2)$, and so $U_1 \cap U_2 = S^3 - (\text{Im}(f_1) \cup \text{Im}(f_2))$.

So you want to compute the homology of $U_1 \cap U_2$. You can do this using the Mayer-Vietoris sequence for the union $S^3 = U_1 \cup U_2$.

Consider for example this portion of the sequence:
$$\underbrace{H_3(U_1)}_{\approx 0} \oplus \underbrace{H_3(U_3)}_{\approx  0} \to \underbrace{H_3(U_1 \cup U_2)}_{H_3(S^3)\approx\mathbb Z} \mapsto H_2(U_1 \cap U_2) \mapsto \underbrace{H_2(U_1)}_{\approx  0} \oplus \underbrace{H_2(U_2)}_{\approx  0}
$$

It follows that $H_2(U_1 \cap U_2) \approx \mathbb Z$. Furthermore, the proof of the Mayer Vietoris sequence is sufficiently explicit that you should be able to use it to produce an explicit 2-cycle representing the generator of $H_2(U_1 \cap U_2)$. The word "explicit" must be taken with a grain of salt, of course, because you are not being given the maps $f_1$ and $f_2$ explicitly. Really what you will do is to produce a formula for that 2-cycle that is expressed *in terms of* $f_1$ and $f_2$.

A similar method for $H_1(U_1 \cap U_2)$ works as well, with an even simpler outcome. It also works for $H_0(U_1 \cap U_2)$ but make sure to use reduced homology to save yourself some headaches.

Comment: Following Hatcher's description of the connection homomorphism, the way one finds a generator of $H_i(U_1\cap U_2)$ is taking a cycle $z$ representing a generator of $H_{i+1}(U_1\cup U_2)$ and by barycentric subdivision writing $z=x+y$ with $x\in C_{i+1}(A)$ and $y\in C_{i+1}(B)$. Then the boundary $\partial x$ represents an element of $H_i(U_1\cap U_2)$. In this case, all I can say is that the subdivision depends on $f_1$ and $f_2$, right?

Comment: Almost, although in the present context I'm not sure what you mean by $A,B$, so I would express this a little differently. In the case $i=2$, for example, one writes $z = x + y$ where the support of the $3$-cycle $x$ contains $\text{Im}(f_1)$ and the support of the $3$-cycle $y$ contains $\text{Im}(f_2)$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $U_1$ and $U_2$, I mixed the notation of the book with yours

Comment: Ah, right, then that makes sense.